# Group requests jmeter jtl result file

Tags: performance, jmeter, load

I have Test plan with a transaction controller Landingpage (containing 10+ requests). since I have clicked generate parent sample I get the complete result of the process (this is desired)

Now when I run Jmeterin non Gui and open the jtl file,  dont get the result of landingpage but the result for every single request.

[image]

How can I run the test plan in non gui mode but still have the result grouped by transaction controllers

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your issue using default [Results File Configuration:](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config)

[image]

You should see each individual request under the "Landing Page" transaction controller **plus 1 extra request** with the name of your Transaction Controller and its response time will be the cumulative response time of all its children.

More information: [What is JMeter’s Transaction Controller?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/JMeter-Transaction-controller-behavior)